# Listing include_directories in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake build in which I'm searching for a bunch of dependencies, i.e. I have many instances of:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SomePackage)
if(SOMEPACKAGE_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SOMEPACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})
  link_libraries(${SOMEPACKAGE_LIBRARIES})
endif(SOMEPACKAGE_FOUND)
```

Now, I want to add a custom command to build a precompiled header file, but to do this I need to know all of the paths added by my `include_directories` calls. How can I get a list of these directories (preferably with the proper -I/path/to/directory format) so that I can add them to my custom command?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use the get_property command to retrieve the value of the directory property
`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`

Something like this:

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
  message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

The value of this directory property only tracks the include_directories commands that have occurred previously in the same CMakeLists file, or that have been inherited from previous occurrences in a parent CMakeLists file. If your find_package and include_directories commands are scattered about throughout many subdirectories, this becomes a challenging issue.

If you get to that point, you may consider overriding the include_directories command with your own function or macro and track the values passed to it yourself. Or, simply accumulate them in a global property or an internal cache variable alongside each call to include_directories.

See the documentation here:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html

Comment: is there a way to get the system includes as opposed to every includes?

example:
`include_directories(SYSTEM system/include)`
`include_directories(local/include)`
`get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY ????)`

Comment: I do not know of a way, but there might be one. Might be worth a question of its own. I would have to dig into the CMake source code to see if I could find a way if the Googs does not easily reveal one...

Comment: ```GET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTY(output INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    MESSAGE(WARNING ${output})```

This will print all ```-I``` dirs like:
 /usr/local/include/

Comment: Some directories can be included through compiler flags, so it can be usefull to print additionally CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS variable (or the corresponding variable of your langage) :
 message(STATUS "CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS}")

Comment: @DLRdave "If your find_package and include_directories commands are scattered about throughout many subdirectories, this becomes a challenging issue." Could somebody please explain that in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Our solution to write include directories added by [conan](https://conan.io/) to a file

```
function(output_conan_include_dirs)
    set(include_dir_str "")
    foreach(DIR ${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        set(include_dir_str "${include_dir_str}${DIR}\n")
    endforeach()

    set(pth "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan-includes.txt")
    file(WRITE "${pth}" "${include_dir_str}")
    message(STATUS "Conan include directories written to: ${pth}")
endfunction()

output_conan_include_dirs()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code suggested in the answer by DLRdave works, thanks! Today I had the same problem, **including** the parentheses in the question: (preferably with the proper -I/path/to/directory format).

I did not find a direct solution in spite of the fact that cmake is bound to do this somewhere inside. The best thing I could come up with is

```
get_directory_property (inc_dirs INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
list(TRANSFORM inc_dirs PREPEND "-I ")
list(JOIN inc_dirs " " INCLUDE_STRING)
```

Is there a way to avoid the intermediate variable??