# Cmake include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) has no effect

Tags: cmake, osx-mavericks

I'm failing to compile libpng16 out of source on OS X Mavericks.
It compiled just fine before I moved upgraded to Mavericks.

I am compiling using `CMake` out-of-source i.e:

```
>cd lpng166
>mkdir build && cd build
>cmake .. && make
```

Which runs with no errors

`Cmake` generates a file `pnglibconf.h` which is then included using `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` in libpngs CMakeLists.txt file.

This apparently does not work, and i get the erroneous output below.

```
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/png16.dir/png.o
In file included from /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:14:
In file included from /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngpriv.h:237:
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.h:917:5: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    png_unknown_chunkp));
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngconf.h:341:70: note: expanded from macro 'PNG_CALLBACK'
#  define PNG_CALLBACK(type, name, args) type (PNGCBAPI name) PNGARG(args)
                                                                     ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngconf.h:116:27: note: expanded from macro 'PNGARG'
#  define PNGARG(arglist) arglist
                          ^
In file included from /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:14:
In file included from /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngpriv.h:761:
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngstruct.h:456:4: error: unknown type name 'png_unknown_chunk'
   png_unknown_chunk unknown_chunk;
   ^
In file included from /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:14:
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngpriv.h:993:11: error: unknown type name 'png_xy'
    const png_xy *xy), PNG_EMPTY);
          ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngpriv.h:206:39: note: expanded from macro 'PNG_INTERNAL_FUNCTION'
      extern PNG_FUNCTION(type, name, args, PNG_EMPTY attributes)
                                      ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/pngconf.h:309:75: note: expanded from macro 'PNG_FUNCTION'
#  define PNG_FUNCTION(type, name, args, attributes) attributes type name args
                                                                          ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3698:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'png_gamma_significant' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      if (png_gamma_significant(gamma_val))
          ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3905:64: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
         png_ptr->screen_gamma > 0 ?  png_reciprocal2(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma,
                                                      ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3914:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'png_reciprocal' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            png_reciprocal(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma));
            ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3914:37: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
            png_reciprocal(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma));
                           ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3918:22: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
            png_ptr->colorspace.gamma/* Probably doing rgb_to_gray */);
            ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3987:60: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
         png_ptr->screen_gamma > 0 ? png_product2(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma,
                                                  ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:3993:63: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
         png_ptr->screen_gamma > 0 ? png_reciprocal2(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma,
                                                     ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:4003:37: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
            png_reciprocal(png_ptr->colorspace.gamma));
                           ~~~~~~~  ^
/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/png.c:4011:22: error: no member named 'colorspace' in 'struct png_struct_def'
            png_ptr->colorspace.gamma/* Probably doing rgb_to_gray */);
            ~~~~~~~  ^
3 warnings and 9 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/png16.dir/png.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/png16.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The build works perfectly fine if I manually copy the generated `pnglibconf.h` into the source directory. This has made me come to the assumption that `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` does not work as it is supposed to.

I have tried to list the include directories using like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904431/2323504) proposes. The output shows that the directory is actually in the include directories for the source. This is really confusing.

```
>cmake ..
-- dir='/opt/local/include'
-- dir='/Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/build'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/xxx/Downloads/lpng166/build
```

I am using CMake version 2.8.12, and the same issue is was with 2.8.10.

Edit:
Changed topic as I have discovered the main issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to rerun `cmake`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Sorry :/

Comment: What error message do you get from `cmake`?

Comment: There are no error messages from cmake.

Comment: Maybe try compiling it using MacPorts or something like that.

Comment: I want to be able to compile it using cmake as I bundle it along with another project I have.

Comment: Works for me (Mountain Lion, Xcode 5.0.1).  Downloaded libpng then `cmake .` and then `make`.  No errors at all.

Comment: I, too, had no problems compiling under Mountain Lion. As I mentioned, this started happening after I upgraded to Mavericks.

Comment: Changed title as I found out it works with in source builds. @trojanfoe can you try to build this out of source?

Comment: I did build from source.  I'm confused; where else would I have built from?

Comment: out of source builds means building outside of the source tree directly. i.e. 
`cd lpng`
`mkdir build`
`cd build`
`cmake ..`
`make` [Search for out of source](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php)