# Compile Eigen + Intel MKL with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, intel-mkl, eigen3

I want to use the Intel MKL libraries (including the Pardiso solver) with Eigen3. When I manually specify the compiler options in CMake I get it to work (for that I've followed the [Intel Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor/)). But I know there is a pre-difined way through `FindBLAS.cmake` together with the `BLA_VENDOR` environment variable, in particular using the [`FindBLAS.cmake`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/d589d86fec2021b50fda7eb8a67134fcb664e246/cmake/FindBLAS.cmake?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) modified by Eigen. Only I'm stuck with this. How should I write my `CMakeLists.txt`?

I should emphesize that use the latests Eigen3 version on a cluster, so have 'installed' it in a non-trivial location in my home-folder. Also after simply using

```
cmake /path/to/eigen3 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$HOME/opt
make install
```

I did not get the third-party CMake files.

---

## Edit

I have found a solution that seems to work properly:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(main)

set(PROJECT_LIBS "")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# find Eigen3, use an environment variable that specifies the root of the Eigen download:
#   export EIGENPATH="/path/to/clone/of/eigen3/"
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{EIGENPATH}/cmake/")
find_package(Eigen3 3.3.0)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# enable Intel-MKL (only for Intel compilers)
# NB requires correct specification of BLA_VENDOR, e.g.
#   export BLA_VENDOR=Intel10_64lp_seq
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
  find_package(BLAS)
  include_directories(${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(PROJECT_LIBS ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
  add_definitions(-DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL)
endif()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_LIBS})
```

> Note that it is important to remark that the 'installation' of Eigen does not work for this solution, as piggy-bagging on pkg-config is not sufficient here. I.e. one should just download/clone Eigen and point CMake to the download location.

Comment: So, when you try to simply use `find_package(NAME)` it doesn't work? Which variables are not set exactly? Which compiler flags are missing?

Comment: @Ptaq666 I added everything I have tried so far (except my own version of  `FindMKL.cmake`, which is irrelevant to this discussion).

Comment: Try to print all of your include directories from CMake. Here is some example how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902149/listing-include-directories-in-cmake. It seems that some of the `findXXX.cmake` scripts is not setting all the appropriate include dirs. A brutal way to fix it is just to add `target_include_directories(appropriate_target PUBLIC DIR_WITH_mkl.h)`.

Comment: @Ptaq666 Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have posted my solution as an edit of my question. Please comment (or change) if you find improvements.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. So it isn't possible at all to `cmake install` Eigen configured with MKL? If this is the case, what would be a nice CMake setup? Like, putting the entire Eigen folder within an "Extern" directory, maybe? And then setup CMakeLists.txt within the Eigen folder explicitly to use MKL.... Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a tad bit late to answer this, but with the recent CMake Versions, you could use the following. This might be a cleaner solution.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
    set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp)
    add_definitions(-DEIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL)
endif()

find_pacakge(BLAS REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
```

Make sure you have run the oneAPI/MKL setup vars script.

`source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` for oneAPI(it is probably best to add it to  `.bashrc`)