# How can I list the PRIVATE, PUBLIC and INTERFACE include directories of a target?

Tags: debugging, cmake, include-path

This question:

[Listing include_directories in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902149/listing-include-directories-in-cmake)

teaches us how to list include directories for a CMake directory. How do we do that for a *target*, and separating the PUBLIC, PRIVATE and INTERFACE directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the same getter works for directories and targets, just with slightly different syntax:

```
get_property(dirs1 TARGET my_target PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

Now, this will get us the union of two sets of include directories: `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE`, but not `INTERFACE`. We also get:

```
get_property(dirs2 TARGET my_target PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

Now:

- The `PUBLIC` directories are dirs1 intersection-with dirs2 (dirs1 ∩ dirs2).
- The `PRIVATE` directories are dirs1 set-minus dirs2 (dirs1 ∖ dirs2).
- The `INTERFACE` directories are dirs2 set-minus dirs1 (dirs2 ∖ dirs1).

As described in the question you linked to, once you have your list of directories, you can print it out like so:

```
foreach(dir ${dirs2})
  message(STATUS "Interface include directory for my_target: ${dir}")
endforeach()
```

If you need to actually, concretely, generate the three lists - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578248/how-do-i-manipulate-cmake-lists-as-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1) about how to perform union, intersection and difference.