# How do I manipulate CMake lists as sets?

Tags: list, cmake, set-operations

In CMake, lists are used extensively. Sometimes you have two lists of items (strings, basically), and you want to consider their intersection, difference or union. Like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577967/1593077) that just came up for me.

How do I produce such intersection, difference or union lists?

Note: The outputs need to have no duplicates, the inputs not really

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose our lists are in variables `S` and `T`.

For the union, write:

```
list(APPEND union_list ${S} ${T})
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES union_list)
```

For set difference, write:

```
list(APPEND S_minus_T ${S})
list(REMOVE_ITEM S_minus_T ${T})
```

And then we use some set identities to obtain the intersection through the symmetric difference:

- S∩T = (S∪T) ∖ (S∆T)
- S∆T = (S∖T) ∪ (T\S)

Comment: I would rather we had more direct set operations, but - for now, I have to live with just this.