# Printing Interface library in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-language, cmake-format

How to print the interface library in **cmake**. Actually i want to do this for a debugging purpose.
so want to know how to print what are all the include directories in that interface library

I have a interface library A which is linked to 2 interface libraries B and C(i.e A includes B and C).
Now i want to know whether A contains all the paths are not..how to check that?

Comment: Have you tried to just print a content of [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property?

Comment: i have updated the question @Tsyvarev.  also how to print the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ?

Comment: See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577966/how-can-i-list-the-private-public-and-interface-include-directories-of-a-target) about printing `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.